# Has anyone encountered a 12+16 to NVME adapter that works?

Tags: ssd

In my work, I end up salvaging a lot of obsolete but fully functional Macbooks. Most of them have fully functional SSDs, but thanks to Apple's proprietary 12+16 connection, they're only useful in other MacBooks.

Of course, plenty of NVME to 12+16 adapters exist for people wanting to put in aftermarket SSDs, but the opposite adapter seems to just... not exist.

With one exception - there's an extremely kludgey looking adapter that shows up on Amazon for about 10 bucks, but every review for it is negative. And it's HUGE.

There are also enclosures for the Apple SSDs, but they cost as much or more than just buying a brand new SSD. So a waste of money.

Has anyone encountered a 12+16 to NVME adapter that works?

Comment: THe only ones I've seen are very expensive, which as you say makes it a waste of money. You can hand in the SSD modules to an Apple Store for recycling.

Comment: Does it have to be in a 2280 form factor, or would a PCI-e 1x card work?